# What does this recommendation mean on InterSystem Russia's github coding guidelines (macro)?

Tags: objectscript

[These coding guidelines](https://github.com/intersystems-ru/cos-guidelines) mention (rightfully so, I believe) to "[...]insert spaces after comma in functions/methods argument list".

Follows an example, but then this comes after:

> For obvious reasons this recommendation not applies to arguments in $$$macro-call, where such extra spaces will break final result.

I'm not a seasoned ObjectScript developer, far from it, so out of curiosity I tried this:

```
ClassMethod foo()
{
    #define concat(%1, %2) %1 _ %2
    w $$$concat("foo", "bar"), !
}
```

And when executing this method it returns the "expected" result:

```
foobar
```

So, what are those "obvious reasons" this recommendation is referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Developers are lazy, and we are not an exception. While [macro-definitions](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS_macros) so flexible, I can write a lot interesting things, to simplify development process.
You can see one of my examples [here](https://github.com/intersystems-ru/cos-guidelines/issues/9) at github.

```
#define NewTempGN(%gn,%i) set %i=$i(^CacheTemp.MyApp),%gn=$name(^CacheTemp.MyApp(%i))
```

you can't add space after comma, because this space also will appear before variable, and such code may became illegal syntactically.

```
$$$NewTempGN(gn, ii)
#; transform to
set  ii=$i(^CacheTemp.MyApp),gn=$name(^CacheTemp.MyApp( ii))
```

One more example

```
#define forAll(%gn,%key) set %key="" for { set %key=$order(@%gn@(%key)) quit:%key=""
#define forEnd }

#; some global structure which you want to write
set gn=$na(^mtemp("test"))
set @gn@("val1")
set @gn@("val2")
set @gn@("val1")

#; and simple use with macro
$$$forAll(gn,val)
   write !,val
$$$forEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

Another reason is that some macro expressions are evaluated **till-first-whitespace**, for example [##if](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS_macros#GCOS_macros_mpp_lbIf)

Comment: You might want to not link to `localhost` :p